# .htaccess 301 redirect not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a basic CMS in PHP/MySQL where content managers can create pages to the system for public viewing. Each page is then available at an url such as `http://www.example.com/pages.php?pid=123`
Now, I want to redirect requests to `http://www.example.com/pages.php?pid=123` to `http://www.example.com/pages.php?pid=456`.

I've already removed the `pid=123` page from the db but because of the cms code the site still returns a 202 when some one tries to access the page. I thought I could use a 301 redirect in `.htaccess` to make the redirect work, i.e.:

```
redirect 301 pages.php?pid=123 http://www.example.com/pages.php?pid=456
```

but this doesn't work, Apache still return 202 when trying to fetch the pid=123 page. Also, I've tried using mod_rewrite, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^pages.php?pid=123$ pages.php?pid=456 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas what could be wrong and how I can fix the 301 redirect?

Comment: Mangled URLs due to SO's stupid spam detection

Comment: Try RewriteRule ^pages.php\?pid=123$ pages.php?pid=456 [R=301,L] (escape the question mark). Just a guess.

Comment: Ivan, sorry, but didn't work. Still get 202 and no redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the redirect in PHP (which probably knows more about what to redirect where) using `header()`.

Please note that `?` is a special character used by regular expressions, so your regex matches `pages.phppid=123` and `pages.phppid=123`.

Even then, I don't think the query string (including the `?pid=123` part) is used in the URL handled by `RewriteRule`, so you would need to use something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=123$
RewriteRule ^pages.php$ pages.php?pid=456 [R=301,L]
```

This shouldn't work as is, but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've already fixed the '?' part per Ivan Krechetov suggestion. The rewrite rule you suggest didn't unfortunatly work, still 202 and no redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Both the [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) work just on the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax). In mod_alias (`Redirect` directive) you can not test the query and in mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` directive) you need an additional [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pid=123(&|$)
RewriteRule ^pages\.php$ /pages.php?pid=456 [R=301,L]
```

But it would certainly be better if your CMS can handle such redirects since it’s your CMS that knows best what URLs are valid and what are not.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried the rewrite above but it doesn't work. Still getting 202 and no redirect, only a page that loads the default php template.

Comment: @Evenz495: Do you use other rules that might get in conflict with this one?

Comment: This answer is golden. If you know that RewriteRule and Redirect don't work on query strings, everything suddenly falls into place and apache redirects are yet again easy. And one hour wrestling with RewriteRule trying to deal with query strings does not seem like much.